# Using command-line argument for reading and writing files to a program

Tags: java, json, eclipse, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use my LoadTextFile() method to read a .txt file from the command prompt in Eclipse and then use another method, SaveDocumentsToJSON, to write into a json.file (again, the name of the json file should be entered as an argument in the command prompt).

My code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // instantiate an instance of the BTextLoader class.
        BTextLoader loader = new BTextLoader();

        // Check if command line arguments are NOT empty and then enter the file names.
        if (args.length > 0) {
            {

// with hard-coded loader.LoadTextFile("TextFile.txt") the next part of the code runs as expected.


                for (int x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
                    if (args[x].endsWith(".txt")) {
                        loader.LoadTextFile(args[x]);
                    }

                    if (args[x].endsWith(".json")) {

                        loader.SaveDocumentsToJSON(args[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            else {
                            System.err.println("No valid file was given.");
            }
        }
    
    public void LoadTextFile(String filePath) {
    
            try {
                System.out.println("Loading file...");
                File inFile = new File(filePath);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
    
                String line = br.readLine();
    
                Integer counter = 0;
                while (line != null)
    
                {
                    if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                        documents.put("doc" + counter, line);
                        ;
                        counter++;
    
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
    
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("File Load Failed");
            }
```

So if I enter the outputFile.json file in the command prompt, and hard code "TextFile.txt", then the result is as expected, with the text file remaining unaltered and a new .json file being created.

However, if I try to use loader.LoadTextFile(args[0])  and enter "TextFile.txt  outputFile.json" (two file names with a space) in Eclipse, then my original TextFile.txt gets rewritten with a json structure and  outputFile.json is not created.

I need help with loading my .txt file and then saving it with the names as command-line arguments. How can I avoid hard coding my .txt file for this to work?

Comment: Does this code work? It looks like there's a for loop over "x" – `for (int x = 0...` – and then _inside_ that loop, there's a second for loop over "x" (and an ensuing compiler error). Elsewhere in the code, there's a call to `documents.put()` with no definition of what `documents` is, something global presumably? This might help: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it does work if I hard-code the part where I load the text file, i.e. loader.LoadTextFile("TextFile.txt")

Answer (score 1):

Whatever parameter matches, you will always overwrite the first given file:

```
for (int x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
    if (args[x].endsWith(".json")) {
        loader.SaveDocumentsToJSON(args[0]);
    }
}
```

You need to change into

```
loader.SaveDocumentsToJSON(args[x]);
```

Yet there is still an imminent problem depending on the sequence of the parameters. Check how your code behaves if you first put the json file and afterwards the txt file. Similarly there is no check if you put several txt or json files. I'm wondering whether all that is intended or unplanned side effects.

Comment: Unfortunately still have this problem. it changes the text file.  I have rewritten the code in my original question to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: I can still see `loader.SaveDocumentsToJSON(args[0]);`